# Vim share Ex commands globally

Tags: vim

In Vim,
I can open **Vim Ex command** Window with **q:**
It seems to me all the commands are not **shared** in other instance of Vim.
e.g. I have other Vim instance in a second console.

I'm wondering whether I can **share** all the Ex commands that I have typed for last ten days

Comment: You can find the history of commands in `.viminfo` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, command history is not shared. Histories (as well as marks, jumps, opened files) are stored in a *viminfo* file. The contents are written when quitting Vim, and read during startup.

But (and here comes the interesting part), you can manually trigger these with the `:rv[iminfo]` and `:wv[iminfo]` commands. So, first execute `:wv` in the one Vim instance to export its history, then import via `:rv` in the second instance. This could even be automated via `:autocmd`s.